# Alterando a cor da box com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Só consigo realizar a alteração de cor apenas uma vez quando passa o mouse, e quando cria algum elemento novo, é sempre a mesma cor do anterior, fazendo assim ficar em um padrão.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Exercicio 7</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <button class="botao">Adicionar um elemento aleatório</button>

    </div>    

</body>

<script>

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = "0123456789ABCDEFG";
        var color = "#";
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16 )];

        }
        return color;
    }
    var newColor = getRandomColor();

    var app = document.querySelector("#app");
    var button = document.querySelector("#app button");

    button.onclick = function() {
        var box = document.createElement('div');
        box.style.width = 100;
        box.style.height = 100;
        box.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
        box.onmouseover = function(){
            box.style.backgroundColor = newColor;

        }
        app.appendChild(box);

    }

</script>

</html>
```

Então eu fiz uma comparação com esse [código](https://github.com/susanabatistas/rocketseat-curso-js/blob/master/modulo2/02.html) e vi que possui pequenas diferenças, mas qual delas está gerando o conflito?

O resultado esperado era que quando passasse o mouse por cima da box, ela então mudaria de cor, independente de quantas vezes você passasse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de gerar uma nova cor a cada clique, ou seja dentro do `onclick` ou do `onmouseover` (dependendo do efeito que procuras)...

Muda `var newColor = getRandomColor();` assim:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = "0123456789ABCDEFG";
  var color = "#";
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

  }
  return color;
}

var app = document.querySelector("#app");
var button = document.querySelector("#app button");

button.onclick = function() {
  
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.style.width = '100px';
  box.style.height = '100px';
  box.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
  box.onmouseover = function() {
    var newColor = getRandomColor();
    box.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  }
  app.appendChild(box);

}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <button class="botao">Adicionar um elemento aleatório</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Então Sérgio, o resultado esperado é quase esse, entretanto quando passasse novamente o mouse na cor do elemento, ele mudaria de cor novamente, poderia destacar qual foi o erro de lógico no meu código? Lamento se não fui muito específico na descrição do problema.

Comment: @RodrigoPires nesse caso o `var newColor = getRandomColor();` deve estar dentro do `onmouseover`... seuindo a mesma lógica que expliquei em cima. Mudei na resposta, testa agora.